# How can I remove a single item in To-Do List using slices

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, slice, redux-toolkit

I have tried using filter method but its not working

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { removeTodo } from "../Redux/Slices/TodoSlices";
// import { delTodo } from "../Redux/Slices/TodoSlices";

function Todos({title}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const  id  = useSelector((state) => state.todos.id);
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    console.log("clicked");
    console.log(id);
    dispatch(removeTodo(id));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className=" relative flex w-[80%] h-8 bg-white mb-1 over">
        <div className="flex-[90%] text-black overflow-y-auto text-sm p-1">
          {title}
        </div>
        <button className=" absolute top-0 right-[-25px] flex-[10%] hover:bg-red-600 w-6 ml-1 h-8">
          <i
            className="fa-solid fa-trash text-white text-center"
            key={id}
            onClick={() => { handleDelete(id)}}
          ></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Todos;
```

My Slices having 3 slices addToDo which adds the todos in Add box, Clear Todo which clears all the Todos onClick, and a remove todo slice which is not working

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const TodoSlice = createSlice({
  name: "todos",
  initialState: { id: 1, title: [], count: 0 },
  reducers: {
    addTodo: (state, action) => {
      const newTodo = {
        id: state.id++,
        title: action.payload.title,
        count: state.count++,
      };
      state.title.push(newTodo);
    },
    clearTodo: (state) => {
      state.title = [];
      state.count = 0;
      state.id = 0;
    },
    removeTodo: (state, action) => {
      // console.log(action.payload.id);
      const todoId = action.payload;
      return state.title.filter((todo) => todo.id !== todoId);
    },
  },
});

export const { addTodo, clearTodo, removeTodo } = TodoSlice.actions;

export default TodoSlice.reducer;
```

If I trying to return the filter method my todos.map is not working , i am getting an error

```
78  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at AddBox (AddBox.jsx:43:16)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:5)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:7)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:20)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26096:20)
AddBox @ AddBox.jsx:43
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26096
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:26201
scheduleRoot @ react-dom.development.js:27810
(anonymous) @ @react-refresh:247
performReactRefresh @ @react-refresh:226
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ @react-refresh:676
validateRefreshBoundaryAndEnqueueUpdate @ @react-refresh:714
(anonymous) @ AddBox.jsx:52
(anonymous) @ client.ts:542
(anonymous) @ client.ts:459
(anonymous) @ client.ts:306
queueUpdate @ client.ts:306
await in queueUpdate (async)
(anonymous) @ client.ts:159
handleMessage @ client.ts:157
(anonymous) @ client.ts:90
Show 19 more frames
```

I am not able to understand what i am doing wrong. please help

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { addTodo } from "../Redux/Slices/TodoSlices";
import Todos from "./Todos";

function AddBox() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todos.title);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (value == ''){
      return
    }
    console.log("clicked");
    dispatch(
      addTodo({
        title: value,
      })
    );
    setValue("");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="w-[100%] flex justify-between items-center">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="additem"
          id="additem"
          placeholder="Add your new Todo"
          className="w-[155px] h-12 my-8 bg-black text-white text-base p-[6px]"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={value}
        />
        <i
          className="fa-solid fa-plus bg-purple-400 h-12 text-center p-2"
          onClick={handleSubmit}
        ></i>
      </div>
      <div className="w-[100%] h-[calc(100%-205px)] text-white text-lg overflow-y-auto">
        {todos.map((item) => {
          console.log(item);
          return <Todos title={item.title} key={item.id} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default AddBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
removeTodo: (state, action) => {
    const todoId = action.payload;
    state.title = state.title.filter((todo) => todo.id !== todoId);
},
```